# django how to get image filaname hosted on S3?

Tags: django, regex, amazon-s3

in models i am making thumbnail from uploaded image and want to save into different folder with the same name:

```
class Ad(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField()
    phone_number = models.CharField
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(
        default='ad_images/default.png', upload_to='ad_images')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(
        default='ad_thumbnails/default.png', upload_to='ad_thumbnails')

    # options of the model
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_posted']

    # this is how the object to be displayed
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('ad-details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk, 'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        output_size = (500, 500)
        img.thumbnail(output_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        thumb_io = BytesIO()
        img.save(thumb_io, 'JPEG', quality=100, subsampling=0)

        # chose same name as original image
        name = os.path.basename(self.image.name)
        # save=False in order not to call super().save() again and again..
        self.thumbnail.save(name, File(thumb_io), save=False)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But S3 doesnt have os.path of course.

Current `self.image.name` is `ad_images/kokokok.jpg`.

So, if you know the regex to get string after the last `/` or any other method?
Is there any way to get filename of an image?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with `os.path`. `os.path` is working normally.

The issue was `img = Image.open(self.image.path)`, but django-storages'
`DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'` doesnt support `path`.

Gives error:
    `raise NotImplementedError("This backend doesn't support absolute paths.") NotImplementedError: This backend doesn't support absolute paths.`

SOLUTION:
change `img = Image.open(self.image.path)` to `img = Image.open(self.image)`

Now it works